# how to display image in jquery in MVC Zend

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, zend-framework, jquery-plugins, datatable

buddy...

i am working in zend MVC, i am loading/using the datatable for the gird view and table tools plugin for the export here is the line of jQuery code which i am using

```
"tableTools": {
         "sSwfPath": "../images/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
     },
```

now when i am loading the page in the browser it is reversing me with an error

```
404 Not Found - http://localhost/oavt/public/admin/members/images/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
```

now my .swf file is been keep under oavt/public/libs/dataTable/images/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"

js is been stored in oavt/public/libs/dataTable/js/datatable.js

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i am not getting image on the screen as it is taking virtual browser path.... i want to add directory path absolute in jquery how to get this???

Answer (score 0):

You must make use of [BaseURL Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl)

In PHP:

```
<?php echo $this->baseUrl('images/logo.jpg'); ?>
```

In JS:

```
"tableTools": {
         "sSwfPath": "<?= $this->baseUrl() ?>../images/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
     },
```

**EDIT:**

Now I'm thinking about it: in some legacy projects I don't make use of the baseURL Helper. I just direct to an image as followed: `/images/myImage.jpg`. Try to leave the '..' out in front of you path. In your .htaccess you must define a RewriteRule so `/images/*.*` in HTML will resolve in `/public/images/*.*`

.htaccess (untested):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/images/(*).(*)$ /images/$1.$2 [L]
```

Comment: when i am checking in my browser DOM is giving me below  line not converting php code 
"<?php $this->baseUrl() ?>../images/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"

Comment: when you use <?php ..?> you must perform an `echo`: `<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>../images/....` without echo you can use <?= .. ?> which stand for direct output.

Comment: i have done the same thing actually i have created one external js file which i kept as plugin for the grid so when every grid is to created this plugin is called. this run proper for the data grid bt not for the tabletools

Comment: Hm that will be the problem I think. I thought de JS-script was embedded within the .phtml of the view. I think with the external file the php-code won't be seen as PHP but text. Maybe the option of the .htaccess (see edited post) is a good approach for you. It works for my legacy projects. or include the external JS in the .phtml